# Group concatenation in Hive sql

Tags: hive, aggregate, hiveql, concatenation, group-concat

I am finding bit challenging to achieve the below task.
Please find the attachment for sample data set and output.
[image]
Basically i want to concatenate in c6 column into 1 with pipe separated for each group

Answer (score 0):

Use **`group by`** and then **`collect_list`** with **`concat_ws`** function.

```
select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,concat_ws("|",collect_list(c6)) c6 from 
  <table_name> 
group by c1,c2,c3,c4,c5;
```

Comment: Thank you shu. I tried this but it seems I am getting last value i.e. Spark Developer for 10104 , 109930 for Hive developer and not the concatenated value .

Comment: Please check are there any white space or extra characters in `c1,c2,c3,c4,c5` columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collect function

using collect()

```
select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,concat_ws("|",collect(c6)) c6 from <table> group by c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
```

Using collect_set()

```
select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,concat_ws("|",collect_set(c6)) c6 from <table> group by c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
```